# React Apollo Client not sending cookies

Tags: express, cookies, react-apollo

I have tried following the instructions on Apollo Client for sending cookies along with the graphql request, but the express server is not receiving any cookies and when I inspect the request it shows that no cookies are being sent with the response.

Following this page:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html

My code is

```
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql',
  opts: {
    credentials: 'include',
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

My setup is very simple, I am just using the create-react-app server on localhost:3000, sending requests on for the api to localhost:5000 (express api server). I can set and retrieve cookies via localhost:3000 on other routes, only Apollo Client is not sending them.

Answer (score 4):

I do not understand this why the documentation says what it does, although perhaps a developer with more experience would not have had a problem.

Anyway, the less experienced developer should note that instead of:

```
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql',
  opts: {
    credentials: 'include',
  }
});
```

It should just be:

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql',
  credentials: 'same-origin'
});
```

In other words, there is no separate `opts` object within the createHttpLink configuration object.

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper from the Apollo Client library called `createNetworkInterface` and you can import it like so:

```
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
```

Then you can implement it like so:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: 
});
```

The Apollo Client assumes that your graphql client on the express side is listening on the endpoint `/graphql`. You can verify this by going to your `server.js` file.

You should see something like:

```
// Instruct Express to pass on any request made to the '/graphql' route
// to the GraphQL instance.
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  expressGraphQL({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
);
```

So the `uri:` option you specify is still GraphQL like so:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: '/graphql'
});
```

We do this because whenever we create our own `networkInterface` it no longer assumes the `uri` is `/graphql` so we have to directly say it.

The part that really matters is the `opts:` property like so:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: '/graphql',
  opts: {
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  }
});
```

This is saying its safe to send along cookies whenever it makes a query to the backend server. So you take this `networkInterface` and pass it along to the Apollo Client like so:

```
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: '/graphql',
  opts: {
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface,
  dataIdFromObject: o => o.id
});
```

So that is pretty much it for getting Apollo to send along cookies along with every single request it makes to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You code should be

```js
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql',
  credentials: 'include'
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

See official doc for details:  [apollo client cookie](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication/#cookie)

Also make sure that your server returns correct value for the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. It should not be equal '*'

Comment: @CSBigSur I will appreciate your vote up if my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

`credentials` are supposed to be mentioned under createHttpLink

```
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql',
  credentials: 'include'
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

In case, you are using `ApolloClient.split`, then you can use

```
const httpLink = ApolloLink.split(
  (operation) => operation.getContext().hasUpload,
  createUploadLink({uri:URI, credentials: 'include'}),
  new HttpLink({uri:URI}),
);

 new ApolloClient({
  link:httpLink,
  cache:new InMemoryCache()
 });
```